# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "414.shtml": No address associated with hostname for Retrofit api hitting

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 for api hitting and parameter is String type.

When string value is small then it's working fine but when string data is large then getting following exception.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "414.shtml": No address associated with hostname
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:125)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:172)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
    at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:106)
enter code here
```

Comment: Did you add INTERNET PERMISSION ??

Comment: 414 is an HTTP error code for "URI too long" - looks like you have a broken redirect to an error page or something like that.

Comment: I already added internet permission and for short request it's working fine, but for long request getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending json in parameters, therefore I was getting `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "414.shtml"`.

For that we have to send json in request body.
Following code for send json using request body.

```
RequestBody body = null;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("data", data);

            body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonObject.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST
    Call<DemoResponse> apitest(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody body);
}
```